# Joining vertical values with horizantal tables titles

Tags: asp-classic

I have two tables. In the first table, the data are vertical order that is in the same column. But in the second table, the datas are horizontal. I have difficulty in joining them. I want to joing values "sin_id" columns in the first table with the columns s1, s2, s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12 and s13 in the second table.
Note: I am using asp classic and access datatable.

[The name of the first table is "Siniflar" It is like that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEkBz.jpg)

[The name of the second table is “tizin25”. It is like that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKHPA.jpg)

```
    How can we success this?
```

Comment: if you're pulling data from the database, you can try to PIVOT the first table to join the two in your SQL expression.

Comment: I don't know pivot codes. Can you write the codes please?

Comment: @MehmetFatihYeşilbaş Please understand that [so] is not a code writing service. People are here to help **you** to solve code related problems, not write code from scratch for you.

Comment: what is the database system you're using, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...?

Comment: I am using sql system.

Comment: they are all sql systems, could you ask somebody who works on the backend "which rdbms you are pulling data from"?